# Why is the this block is not performed during execution?

Tags: java

```
int n = 3;
int x = n;
int y = 0;
for(int i = n; i > 0; i--)
    for(int j = 0; j <=n; j++)
        if(j > n)
            for(int k = 1; k <=n; k++)
                System.out.println("x is " +x--);
        else
            System.out.print("y is " +y++);
```

under the if statement if(j > n) why is that the for loop is not performed?
i can't really understand why, because our instructor let us analyze the running time and i can't really understand why that for loop is not performed during the execution. please help me..

Comment: What do you think `for(int j = 0; j <=n; j++)` means? Can you describe in words the possible values of j? Which of them satisfy `if(j > n)`?

Comment: At what point do you expect `j > n` to be true and why?  *"our instructor let us analyze the running time"* - Is "analyze the running time" another term for using a debugger?  Because this is a great opportunity to use a debugger to step through the code as it executes and observe the changing values of the variables.  When you do this, what specific operation produces an unexpected result?  What result was expected?

Answer (score 2):

```java
for(int j = 0; j <=n; j++)
    if(j > n)
```

What you are saying in the `for` loop is: Execute this code while `j` is `less or equal` to `n`.

Then on the `if` you say: If `j` `is greater` than `n`.

`j` will never be greater than `n` as the `for` loop limits `j` falue to be `less or equal` than `n`.

That's pretty basic and you should read more on how `for` works.

Also, avoid not using `{}`, it's very dangerous. Prefer to always do:

```java
for(int j = 0; j <=n; j++) {
    if(j > n) {
         ....
    }
}
```

Comment: As you are new to StackOverflow, don't forget to accept an answer that satisfies your question.

Comment: But also, you should wait a while before accepting an answer, in case other people come along with answers that suit you better.